# How to select ith column of a table in SQL?

Tags: sql

Say we have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table
(
  regionname character varying(10),
  year integer,
  month integer,
  value integer
)
```

How to select for example the 3rd column "month" without using

```
SELECT month FROM new_table
```

but something like

```
SELECT "the 3rd column" FROM new_table
```

Comment: use the schema info to generate a dynamic query based on your column number

Comment: Can you specify it for this example?

Comment: In general: no this can't be done. You should also add a tag for the DBMS you are using. Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: This doesn't reply your question but with SQL Server you may do 
`SELECT month FROM new_table order by 1`
and this would order the result using month column. I have never seen such a way as you described. Can you tell us more on what you are trying to achieve? Maybe we could come up with an out-of-box idea.

Answer (score 0):

I want to first say that a table schema could change, so the column order could change, thus breaking any existing queries, stored procedures, or code outside your database. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Do you just want to use numbers instead of names?

This answer:

```
Declare @WhichOne int;
Declare @Sql varchar(200);
Set @WhichOne = 2;
With cte As
(Select name, Row_Number() Over (Order By column_id) As rn
From sys.columns
Where Object_Name(object_id) = 'MyTable')
Select @Sql = 'Select ' + QuoteName(name) + ' From MyTable'
From cte
Where rn = @WhichOne;
Exec(@Sql);
```

Can be found here: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/148495/Solved-SELECT-columns-by-column-index-NOT-by-colu

Comment: How do you know he/she is using SQL Server?

Comment: I don't. All I know is the post is tagged as SQL.

Comment: SQL is a *query* language, it's not a specific DBMS product.